# Spring native generation with multi module spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-native

having a spring boot multi module application. Wanted to convert in spring native exe on windows. Also need to support third party lib as well. I am having 5 modules in my spring boot application:

1. Security (user management generates JWT and validate before each request).
2. Spring boot main application.
3. Configuration -  use to do my application configuration)
4. UI (angular code )
5. Reporting (generates reports from DB)

I am able to create exe via maven AOT plugin. (did lot of configuration for initialize at run time and build time) exe is generated with following files:

```
            target\application.exe (executable)
            target\awt.dll (jdk_lib)
            target\jaas.dll (jdk_lib)
            target\javaaccessbridge.dll (jdk_lib)
            target\jawt.dll (jdk_lib)
            target\management.dll (jdk_lib)
            target\sunmscapi.dll (jdk_lib)
            target\w2k_lsa_auth.dll (jdk_lib)
            target\java.dll (jdk_lib_shim)
            target\jvm.dll (jdk_lib_shim)
            target\cpos-admin-portal-application.build_artifacts.txt

    target\cpos-admin-portal-application.exe
          .   ____          _            __ _ _
         /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
        ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
         \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
          '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
         =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
         :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.6)
```

but no hit goes to any controller. Not other logs of starting application is printed
When I start exe, application use to start  following prints on console
Not getting why this much type of files has been generated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: update the issue

Comment: Hi All, can someone help me ?